# CodeIgniter caching

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching

Im developing a page in CodeIgniter, however I am suddently having a problem about caching.

When i do a change, there goes 10 minutes before the change takes action - properbly because of Caching. 
I have added tried to add all this to my controller constructor with out an effect:

```
$this->output->set_header("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
$this->output->set_header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
$this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
$this->output->set_header("Expires: ". gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s')."GMT");
$this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0");
$this->output->set_header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
$this->output->cache(0);
```

Any know what is wrong? Or have any tip? It is horrible to develope like this...

Comment: Are you using `$this->output->cache()` ?

Comment: please try refreshing your page with ctrl+f5 instead regular (just) f5 .